# Conditional probability and relation between random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let's have three random variables $X,Y,Z\in \mathbb{R}$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent and let's assume that $\forall A \in B(\mathbb{R}), \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$, $P(Z \in A|Y=y)=P(Xy \in A)\bigr)$.
Where $B(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, is it true that $\forall A \in B(\mathbb{R}), P(Z\in A)=P(XY \in A)$?

Can you prove it or can you suggest me how to prove it?

Comment: What do you think $Z/Y = X\cdot Y$ mean?

Comment: @kludg the conditioning, i edited the symbol becuase i saw that it's frequently used | istead of /

Comment: There is no such thing as conditional random variable.

Comment: @kludg sorry, i have been not formal, i will edit and try to get more formal

Comment: Use the Law of Total Probability.